# 'For loop' doesn't finish for some reason

Tags: java, for-loop

I have an array that I'm trying to blur using a kernel, but the loop doesn't finish for some reason, here's the code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
                for (int kx = -2; x <= 6; x++) {
                    for (int ky = -2; y <= 6; y++) {

                        nlm2[x][y] += 100 * (int) ((float) nlm[x][y]*(float)kernel[(kx+3)*(ky+3)-1]);
                        System.out.println(x+" "+y);

                        System.out.println(kx+" NLM: "+(float) nlm[x][y]);
                        System.out.println(ky+" Kernel: "+(float)kernel[(kx+3)*(ky+3)-1]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It seems to stop after 
x = 0; y = 6
kx = ky = -2

There are no errors in the console, and it shows another print screen after this little loop-de-loop.

Comment: Debugging is the best thing since sliced bread, but only when you do it yourself.

Comment: Your inner-most loop increments and tests `y` value instead of `ky`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This lines might be the problem.-

```
for (int kx = -2; x <= 6; x++) {
    for (int ky = -2; y <= 6; y++) {
```

You're incrementing `x` and `y` respectively, instead of `kx` and `ky`.

I'm guessing you really meant.-

```
for (int kx = -2; kx <= 6; kx ++) {
    for (int ky = -2; ky <= 6; ky ++) {
```